# GORM don't use underscores in tablenames

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm attempting to use GORM with a database originally developed with Django.

The issue I'm running into is that the tables created by Django follow the format app_name_tablename. I am using the TablePrefix option to add that app_name_ part, but I cannot find an option to prevent GORM from automatically using underscores in the name. The Gorm docs don't seem to reference an option to remove this underscore.

Obviously I can define the tablename manually on each of the models, however I'd rather avoiding doing this. Is there an option in the Gorm config to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `NoLowerCase`

```
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{
  NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
    TablePrefix: "t_",   // table name prefix, table for `User` would be `t_users`
    SingularTable: true, // use singular table name, table for `User` would be `user` with this option enabled
    NoLowerCase: true, // skip the snake_casing of names
    NameReplacer: strings.NewReplacer("CID", "Cid"), // use name replacer to change struct/field name before convert it to db name
  },
})
```

https://gorm.io/docs/gorm_config.html#NamingStrategy

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `TableName() string` function in your entity which will force gorm to use that name.

e.g:

```
type OrganizationGroup struct {
  Name string
}

func (o OrganizationGroup) TableName() string {
    return "OrganizationGroups"
}
```